# Codeception with Paypal Sandbox: Cannot select injected Ajax Fields

Tags: selenium, xpath, codeception

Problem: When I am redirected from my domain to sandbox.paypal.com, I can't select the input fields using XPATH selectors. An error saying element not found gets thrown up. I have tried using a js selector as well but I get the following error: Cannot set property 'value' of null.

I have tried manually visiting the page and applying the xpath, and it works perfectly fine. Any ideas?

Here's the Xpath script in question:

```
'//input[@name="login_email"]';
```

Here's the JS Script that also fails:

```
return document.querySelector('login_emaildiv input';
```

I have noticed that the form is injected into the DOM. Would anyone know a workaround?

I have tried this with the chromedriver as well as the firefox one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with iFrames. Since the content was injected into an iFrame, codeception needs to switch context. Here's the solution:

1. Loop through the list of frames on the page
2. When you find the
   frame that has your element (example:
   `frame[i].document.getElementById("yourElementId")` ),grab the name
   of the frame
3. On codeception switch the context like so:

   `$this->I->switchToIFrame('frameName');`

Answer (score 1):

You may try using JavaScriptExecutor like below

```
if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementsByName('login_email')[0].value='Enter your Value';");
```

}